# Applying as.Date to Excel format dates in R

Tags: r, excel, date, format

I want to convert an Excel format date into yyyy-mm-dd in order to convert a data.frame in a zoo object.

Using the two following formulas does not give the same result?

Why does that happen?

```
> as.Date(41375, origin = "1899-12-30")
[1] "2013-04-11"

> as.Date(41375, tz = "CET")
[1] "2083-04-13"
```

Comment: Your second example results in an error: `Error in as.Date.numeric(41375, tz = "CET") : 'origin' must be supplied` If you don't get this error, you are doing something different than what you show us.

Answer (score 7):

`"Date"` class has no time zones so `tz=` is meaningless.  I assume you have the zoo package loaded in which case `origin = "1970-01-01"` is supplied as the default so the second line of code in the question is the same as:

```
as.Date(41375, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

There is a discussion of Excel dates and R in the *Help Desk* article of [R News 4/1](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf).